# Navigate to another app with navigation component and composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I'm creating an app with navigation component and composable. Imagine that I have an Android app with `navHost` like this:

```kotlin
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = RallyScreen.Overview.name,
    modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
) {
    composable(RallyScreen.Overview.name) { 
      Text(RallyScreen.Overview.name)
    }
    composable(RallyScreen.Accounts.name) {
        Text(RallyScreen.Accounts.name) 
    }
    composable(RallyScreen.Bills.name) { 
        Text(RallyScreen.Bills.name) 
    }
}
```

I wonder how can I define navigation to another app like Gmail, or any other apps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone more experienced will correct me, but I think this is not the correct way to approach the problem.
In a nutshell, the [NavHost](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#create-navhost) is used to link `routes` to `composables` functions of your app, and handle the in-app navigation. Why you want to create a link to another app here? What are you trying to do ?

Rather, in one of your composables functions, you will have for example a button, which [starts an activity with an intent](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending#StartActivity).

```
Button(
    onClick = { startActivity(intent) }
) {
    Text(text = "Button")
}
```

You can also do this with the `BottomNavigation` by using the `onClick` property of the `BottomNavigationItem`.